# Include error with # include <sys/wait.h>

Tags: c, include

so im working on a C program that implements collatz conjecture and my code seems to be fine on a friends desktop but on mine it gives me an include error for the include message`#include <sys/wait.h>`

this is the entire code here

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <unistd.h>
# include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc , char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("please provide a number \n");
        return 1;
    }
     if (argc >2) {
        printf("please provide only 1 number \n");
        return 1;
    }

    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (n <= 0) {
        printf("please provide a positive number\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int rc = fork();
    if (rc == 0) {
        while (n != 1) {
            if (n % 2 == 0) {
                n = n / 2;
            } else {
                n = 3 * n + 1;
            }
            printf("%d\n", n);
        }
    } else if (rc > 0) {
        wait(NULL);
    } else {
        printf("fork failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sys/wait.h` is not in the standard C. What environment (OS and compiler) are you using?

Comment: @MikeCAT It *is* [a POSIX header](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/sys_wait.h.html#tag_13_71), though.  I suspect Windows.

Comment: @MikeCAT  im using windows is there any way for me to add sys/wait to it?

Comment: Set up a WSL2 instance and use it to build and run the program.